# What are the two IPA systems, /ˈfoɚ/ and /fɔːr/?

Tags: ipa

For the word "for" in AmE strong sound, [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/for) gives this IPA symbol /fɔːr/ while Merriam-Webster gives /ˈfoɚ/.

It seems to two different IPA systems, are't they? What are the names of the IPA systems/types?

Comment: Maybe it's two regional accents.

Comment: You mean they are in the same IPA system, right?

Comment: There are not "two different IPA systems". There are many different ways of using IPA, depending on how precisely you want to describe the sounds. But there is no way that those two representations can depict the same sounds. The quality of the 'o' is different, and the MW is apparently bisyllabic.

Comment: @ColinFine Thank you. I got it. Would please explain a bit more about "precisely"? For example, regarding to the sound in question, which version is more precise?

Comment: @shi95. It doesn't work like that. Neither is more precise: they are different, (and, I would say, incompatible, which is why others have suggested they represent two accents). But in writing in IPA, you choose how precise you want to be, according to the purpose. For example, the tongue is higher and more forward for the /k/ in _cot_ relative to the /k/ in _kit_. We don't notice they are different in English, but for some languages they would be distinct.  So depending on the purpose you might choose to ignore that difference and write them the same in IPA or you might not.